# Compound component: How to pass information to the parent

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to write a map component for angular that takes marker components.

```html
<app-map>
  <app-marker 
    *ngFor="let device of (devices$ | async)" 
    [position]="device.position"></app-marker>
</app-map>
```

I want the marker component to be able to notify the map component of any new position.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-marker',
  templateUrl: './marker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./marker.component.scss']
})
export class MarkerComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
  @Input() position: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Here is the map component:

```js
import { QueryList, Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { Map } from '../../map';
import { MarkerComponent } from '../marker/marker.component';

declare var H: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.scss']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  private map: any;

  @Output() event: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  @ViewChild('map')
  public mapElement: ElementRef;

  @ViewChildren(MarkerComponent) markers: QueryList<MarkerComponent>;

  constructor() {
    this.map = new Map();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.map.init(this.mapElement);
    this.markers.changes.subscribe(changes => console.log(changes));
  }
}
```

However the map component is never notified of any change. So what would be the right approach in that case?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, i think you need something like using `onChanges`. Here is the link with all the info:
[link](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)

And maybe make use of a service that notify the other component when a change is detected.

Comment: Hey @AlbertoAM so that would be for the child component?

Comment: Hi @m0g , yes if i'm not mistaken you wanted to notify the parent when the children has changes. right?

so an approach can be what i said:
1-create ngOnchanges on the child
2-on that method use a service to notify the parent.

here is the service documentation:
[services](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to observe the changes of the child from the parent, you can bubble the changes up to the parent from the child.

To do that, you can use the `@Output()` decorator inside the child.

[Check out this demo to see it in action.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gpza4q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html)